# Getting error "Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'S:\' because it does not exist." while trying to copy file from Azure VM

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to copy file from one directory on Azure VM to other located outside of VM. I created a script to cover that:

```
[pscredential]$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ComputerUserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ComputerUserPassword -AsPlainText -Force))
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerIP -Credential $credObject -Name ToAzure
try
{
  #Set credential for copy file
  $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $UserPassword -AsPlainText -Force))

  #Create a mapped network drive
  New-PSDrive -Name "S" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $DestinationDirectory -Credential $Credentials -Persist

  #Copy file to destination folder
  Copy-Item -Path $WorkingDirectory -Destination S:\ -ToSession $session -Force
}
```

It seems that PSDrive is created but got error that `Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'S:\' because it does not exist.`

Why do I getting that error ?

When I try to run Copy-Item without -ToSession parameter got error that cannot find path under $WorkingDirectory

Comment: If `$WorkingDirectory` and `$DestinationDirectory` are UNC paths, have you tried copying directly and not creating a PSDrive?

Comment: To precise - I run this script on Azure VM. `$WorkingDirectory` is path directly on this machine ('C:\TestOutput') but `$DestinationDirectory` is a directory on the server which needs authorization. That's why I'm creating PSDrive (no possible to pass credentials using Copy-Item cmdlet). So drive `S:` needs to be created on Azure VM as a path to other directory on server which access is not granted to the user on which I'm logging in on Azure VM

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I figured it out. I made a mistake in `Copy-Item` cmdlet. I'm trying to copy file from Azure VM so I should use parameter `-FromSession` not `-ToSession`. With proper parameter it is working as expected.